# How can I call clearInterval() from another function where setInterval() is defined (functions are in the same class))

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I want to stop setInterval from another function defines in the same class :

```
class A 
 {
      blink(){};
      stopBlink(){};
   }
  class B extends A 
  {
constructor(oldMaterial)
{
   super();
   this.oldMaterial=oldMaterial;
   this.interval=null;
   this.blink=this.blink.bind(this);
   this.stopBlink=this.stopBlink.bind(this);
}
blink(obj,delay,box,duration)
    {
        var changeMaterial= function(obj,newMaterial)
            {
                {
                    obj.material=newMaterial;
                }
            }

        this.interval=(function()
            {
                var Toggle=true
                    return setInterval(function()
                        {
                            if(Toggle)
                                changeMaterial(obj,box);
                            else
                                {                                       changeMaterial(obj,OriginalStairMaterial);
                                }
                            Toggle=!Toggle;
                        }
                    , delay);
                })();
}

stopBlink(obj,duration)
    {
            setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        obj.material=oldMaterial;

                                clearInterval(this.interval);

                    },duration);
    }   
    }
```

I bind() this in order to be accessible in the stopBlink() function, but setInterval() doesn't stop when stopBlink() is called. I don't want to use Interval as a global variable :(

Best Regards

Anes

Comment: use setTimeout with arrow function so that this can refer to class (this object).

Comment: or declare const self = this; before setTimeout
then use 
clearInterval(self.interval);

Comment: I tried to declare const self =this; and it doesn't work (setInterval doesn't stop), I used setTimeout() with flesh arrows setTimeout(()=>{obj.material=oldMaterial;
clearInterval(this.interval);},duration); doesn't work too

Comment: check inside setTimeout console the value of this.interval

Comment: yes I check it inside the blink() function after setInterval it gives 11 and then inside setTime out it gives 13 (depending on number of blinks)

Comment: it should not change. How you are using it? is there any chance you are calling blink multiple time that replace this.interval?

Comment: no I just console.log(this.interval) in the end of blink() and then console it again before clearInterval(), I call Blink() when I click to the button and call stopBlink() when I click again and so on

Comment: it seems this.interval is changing. Try changing this.interval in array and push setinterval into that array and console that array when you are calling clearInterval check how many elements it has. if it has more than one then clear all intervals and empty the this.interval

Comment: can u explain what do u mean I didn't understand

Comment: i think this.interval value is changing. so i want you to create this.interval to array and push setInterval into that array instead of assigning directly... in stopBlink console this.interval check length of array if its more than one then blink function triggering multiple time which is replacing this.interval